# For 70,000 rows, my macro is taking a lot of time to give output comment as per various conditions

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

For traversing 70,000 rows (using for loop), my macro is taking a lot of time to give output comment as per various conditions. I am looking to optimise this.

Please see the image that depicts how data looks.

[image]

This code compares various columns and gives output on the basis of certain conditions.

```
Set wsa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audit-NIMS vs Site Topology")

With wsa
AudLastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Cells(1, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "Match;Issue Type;Actions"

For l = 2 To AudLastRow
    aPRTS = .Cells(l, AudLastCol).Value
    bNIMS = .Cells(l, NIMsLastCol).Value
    tempin = .Cells(l, 2).Value

    If aPRTS = bNIMS Then
        Deployed19 = Application.Match("Deployed(1.9)", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(Deployed19) Then
            d19 = .Cells(l, Deployed19).Value
        Else
            d19 = 0
        End If
        Deployed800 = Application.Match("Deployed (800)", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(Deployed800) Then
            d8 = .Cells(l, Deployed800).Value
        Else
            d8 = 0
        End If
        Deployed2500 = Application.Match("Deployed (2.5)", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(Deployed2500) Then
            d25 = .Cells(l, Deployed2500).Value
        Else
            d25 = 0
        End If

        PRTS800 = Application.Match("Total-800-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(PRTS800) Then
            p8 = .Cells(l, PRTS800).Value
        Else
            p8 = 0
        End If

        PRTS1900 = Application.Match("Total-1900-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(PRTS1900) Then
            p19 = .Cells(l, PRTS1900).Value
        Else
            p19 = 0
        End If

        PRTS2500 = Application.Match("Total-2500-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(PRTS2500) Then
            p25 = .Cells(l, PRTS2500).Value
        Else
            p25 = 0
        End If
        If (p19 = d19) And (p8 = d8) And (p25 = d25) Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "TRUE;None;No Action Required."
        Else
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "FALSE;Both;Update NIMS and PRTS."
        End If
    ElseIf aPRTS = "NA" And bNIMS = "0" Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "TRUE;None;No Action Required."
    ElseIf aPRTS = "0" And bNIMS = "NA" Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "TRUE;None;No Action Required."
    ElseIf aPRTS > 0 And bNIMS = "NA" Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "N/A;NIMS;Update NIMS."
    ElseIf bNIMS > 0 And aPRTS = "NA" Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "N/A;PRTS;Check traffic from PRTS & Report to PRTS Team."
    ElseIf bNIMS > aPRTS Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "FALSE;PRTS;Check traffic from PRTS & Report to PRTS Team."
    ElseIf bNIMS < aPRTS Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "FALSE;NIMS;Update NIMS."
    End If
    'To compare certain category of Name and concatenate output accordingly.
    If InStr(1, .Cells(l, 1).Value, "52XC") > 0 Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "Clearwire Site."
    ElseIf InStr(1, .Cells(l, 1).Value, "82XC") > 0 Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "Clearwire Site."
    ElseIf InStr(1, .Cells(l, 1).Value, "XT") > 0 Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "COW Site."
    End If

    If bNIMS = "NA" And Application.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NIMS dump-SC level").Range("B1:B" & temprow), .Cells(l, 2).Value) Then
        .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "Present in NIMS Dump."
    End If
Next l
End With
```

Comment: Use Variant Arrays to iterate instead of iterating the range directly.  Limit the number of times the worksheet is referenced.  Every time it is referenced it slows down the code.  If you wan more help with working code please post on [codereview.se].  It is considered too broad here.

Comment: Have you tried suspending screen updating and auto calculation?  Put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the beginning of your code and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` at the end to turn screen updating and auto calc back on once finished.

Comment: In addition to what others have note, if p19 <> d19 then you don't need to generate or check p8, d8, p25 or d25 - some re-arrangement there would save you time.